# Best way to create an IBM MQ connection on same server

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Connecting to IBM MQ using java but both application and MQ reside on same server. In this case do I need to specify host,port,channel etc., or is only Queue Manager fine, or any better approach.

I am aware how to connect by using host, port, channel and queue name.

What is the best approach to connect when both application and queue manager reside on the same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both application and queue manager are running on the same machine, you do not need to connect using a client connection (that is using host, port and channel name), but can instead use what is known as a local bindings connection, and just provide the queue manager name.

For a client connection, the connection to the queue manager is made over a TCP/IP socket.

For a local bindings connection, the connection to the queue manager is made used shared memory.

Depending on which MQ Java interface you are using, take a look at the following samples.

**IBM MQ Classes for Java**

Look at the sample MQSample.java which makes a very simple local bindings connection.

**IBM MQ Class for JMS**

Look at the JmsBrowser sample as an example. It can use either client or local bindings conncetions. Look at the boolean `clientTransport` and follow the code accordingly.

Comment: Do I need to configure local queues or any other configuration if connecting through binding mode ?

Comment: You need much less configuration for local bindings mode than you do for client connection mode. A client connection will need a running TCP/IP listener, a SVRCONN channel and some channel related security rules, as well as authority to use the queue. A local bindings connection will only require authority to use the queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about JMS, you can do it like this (omitting error handling):

```
  MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("");
  int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
  MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue("Q1", openOptions);

  MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
  queue.get(mqMsg);
  System.err.println("received: " + mqMsg.readLine() );

  queue.close();
  qMgr.disconnect();
```

Comment: This code would connect to the default queue manager. If you don't have a default queue manager, or if you want to use another non-default queue manager you must supply the name of the queue manager in `MQQueueManager`.

Comment: agreed, if you didn't setup a default QMgr, use: new MQQueueManager(qmgrName)

Comment: Now I am getting the below error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager (initialization failure). I have added the following jars: javax.jms-api, com.ibm.mq.allclient, com.ibm.mq.jmqi,com.ibm.mqjms. Did I missed any thing ?

Comment: you should have java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar in your classpath